# Есть HTML код батарейки. Как разделить заряд батарейки на блоки, как показано на рисунке

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Непосредственно ссылка на код.
```

https://codepen.io/FuZzZo/pen/rrWaqR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.battery {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.battery::after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #000;
  top: -15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
}
.red,
.yellow,
.green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.yellow,
.green,
.red,
.orange {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.yellow div,
.red div,
.green div,
.orange div {
  padding: 4.5px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.yellow div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.red div {
  background-color: red;
}
.green div {
  background-color: green;
}
.orange div {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery">
  <div class="white"></div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="red">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="orange">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="yellow">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="green">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мой вариант не слишком красив, но тоже имеет право на жизнь

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно использовать свойство flex

CSS

```css
.battery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.battery::after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #000;
  top: -15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.part {
  width: 36px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery">
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="part red"></div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="part orange"></div>
  <div class="part orange"></div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="part yellow"></div>
  <div class="part yellow"></div>
  <div class="part yellow"></div>
</div>
<div class="battery">
  <div class="part green"></div>
  <div class="part green"></div>
  <div class="part green"></div>
  <div class="part green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мб я где-то ошибся, но верхушки батареек "уползли" =)

Comment: Может быть, сейчас вроде все нормально. Правил код в части содержимого батареек)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать фишку с linear-gradient
на примере вашего класса **.red**, замените его атрибут **background-color** на

```
 background-image: 
 repeating-linear-gradient(
  white,
  white10px,
  red 10px,
  red 20px /* determines size */
);
```

это позволит избежать множества `<div>` в вашей разметке